# How to handle "405 error, Method Not Allowed." without an exception

Tags: c#, exception, httpwebrequest, getresponse

Right now I am solving an issue that I made a `HttpWebRequest` to server and checking if the server answers. Any answer which means that the server was reached is positive for me. So if I will get an answer:

- HttpStatusCode.OK (it's ok for me)
- 405 Method not allowed (it's ok for me).

Code:

```
try
{
    var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_endPointUri);
    myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = _timeoutMs;

    var myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        return true;
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    return e.Message.Contains("The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
return false;
```

How to handle this situation without any exception?

Comment: `... || myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed) return true;`? Side note: never rely on `exception.Message.Contains` because you'd run into localization issues.

Comment: Plus, is 404 not OK?

Comment: If the port is not listening, you still get a WebException. But there is hope. Just check if `e.Response` is null or not. The existence of `e.Response` ensures a response, whatever the status code, has been returned by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to handle the exception, but you can use pattern matching and the `Status` property on `WebException` (which contains a [WebExceptionStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexceptionstatus?view=netcore-3.1)) to control your interpretation of the response more easily:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Timeout = timeout;

try
{
    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    return true;
}
catch (WebException connectionError) when (
    connectionError.Status == WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure ||
    connectionError.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
{
    return false;
}
catch
{
    return true;
}
```

Here is [a dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vxAz4g) that uses the above code to determine whether or not an endpoint 'exists' in 4 different scenarios: (1) the uri is accessible and returns an 'OK' status code, (2) the uri can't be resolved, (3) the uri 'exists' but times out, and (4) the uri exists and returns a 405.

You can edit the conditional patterns in the exception handling to fill out your requirements for additional scenarios.